# React webpack undefined react in console

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have problem with webpack build I write custom webpack config:
https://github.com/Simproduction/react-client-webpack
but when I run dev or build a project everything work correct but I can't call React from console or use react developers tools
I get error 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined(…)`
Could you help me?

My test project,
https://github.com/Simproduction/react-CM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expose React so it is available on the window using the [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack/expose-loader):

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    { test: require.resolve("react"), loader: "expose?React" },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It contains AMD and CommonJS in webpack. You know js loader, right?
If you use AMD ,you know that all js code are in '`define([],function(){ var a=10; ...})` area. if you want print `a` in console. You should like this

```
define([],function(){ 
 var a=10; 
 window.a = a;
})
```

so, you can edit your `main.js`. Add this line `window.React = React;` , but we may use CDN instead of it is common solution.